# Jetty Deployment Order

Tags: deployment, jetty, web-deployment, jetty-8

I have multiple wars getting deployed in jetty 8.1.4 using ContextAppProvider. we want to specify the order in which war apps are deployed, as we have some wars depend on other wars.

So how to set the specific order of deployment in jetty

Answer (score 0):

2 Strategies:

1. Embed the common code into all wars, so there is no required deployment order.
2. Build the common code into a library jar, and put this jar on the jetty classpath, so that it is available to all wars.